# Laravel 5.4 pass variable from controller to js script

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

Hi it is possible pass variable from controller to JS script. I must do change color event when user join to event.

I need pass variable $colorrr to my js becouse i use fullcalendar there is option eventColor: and i want send there variable $colorrr from controller. 
Now only i do checking if event exist in pivot table. And its working, my problem is i dont know how pass variable to option eventColor

Controller:

```html
public function index()
    { 
       $eventscolo=DB::table('save_events')->select('events_id')->get();
       $eventsss=DB::table('events')->select('id','title')->get(); 
             
        foreach ($eventsss as $eventss) 
        {
             
            if(DB::table('save_events')->where('events_id','=',$eventss->id)->exists())
            {
                    
                  $colorrr = 'grey';
                    
            }
            else
                { 
                    if ($eventss->title=="Wydzial 1") 
                        {
                            
                           $colorrr = 'red';
                            
                        }
                            elseif($eventss->title == "Wydzial 2")
                            {
                               
                             $colorrr = 'blue';
                               
                            }
                            elseif ($eventss->title == "Wydzial 3") 
                            {
                               
                             $colorrr = 'green';
                               
                            }
                            elseif ($eventss->title == "Wydzial 4") 
                            {
                                
                               $colorrr = 'yellow';
                                
                            }
                } 

        }
      return view('home',['eventscolo'=>$eventscolo,'eventsss'=>$eventsss,'colorrr'=>$colorrr]);
```

JS script:

```js
<script src="{{ asset('js/fullcalendar') }}/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
    
    var base_url = '{{ url('/') }}';
    
      
    
    $('#bootstrapModalFullCalendar').fullCalendar({
      weekends: true,
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek'
      },
       eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
          $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
          $('#modalBody').html(event.name);
          $('#eventUrl').attr('href','/home/zapis/'+event.id);
          $("#startTime").html(moment(event.start).format('HH:mm '));
          if (event.end) $("#endTime").html(moment(event.end).format('HH:mm '));
          else $("#endTime").html('');              
          $('#fullCalModal').modal();
          return false;
        },
      
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      FirstDay: 1,
              contentheight : 650,
              editable : true,
              allDay : false,
              aspectRatio : 2,
              slotLabelFormat : 'HH:mm:ss',
              timeFormat : 'HH:mm',
              displayEventEnd : true,
              events: {
        url: base_url + '/api',
        error: function() {
          alert("cannot load json");
        }
      },
       eventColor: 'colorrr',
    
      
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: yes you can do that, pass your variable to view and on your view create a js variable and put that value there

Comment: But how i trying do eventColor: {{$colorrr}} and its not working

Comment: and i trying that var colorrr = {{$colorrr}} then eventColor: colorrr, and still dont work

Answer (score 2):

Controller (Pass value like following to your view)

```
//..........................
//............................
$data['myVal'] = "abc";
return view('myViewPage',['data'=>$data]);
```

Blade-myViewPage(JS)

```
<script>
    //Global variable on you blade
    var url = "{{url('/manufacturers-json')}}";
    var custom_val = "{{$data['myVal']}}"; //What ever you are getting from controller ($colorr)
</script>
```

and then you can use this JS variable into your JS. I am doing this way using **angularJS.**
If in your case the above will not work then try creating an input field.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $colorrr; ?>" id="my_color" />
```

Where `$colorrr` (or what ever you are passing from your controller to the view, make sure this variable contains value.
and in your JS.

```
var color = $("#my_color").val();
```

Comment: i made like u write and change all event to red and its not good

Comment: Okay, Can you just print your varibale on your blade (view). If yes then create an input field with type hidden and put value as `{{$colorrr}}` (whatever your variable is) and then get that value using ID of the input Filed using JQUERY

Comment: i made it and its all red when i go to view-source in chrome i saw somethink like that <input type="hidden" value="red" id="my_color" />

Comment: i made that:  <input type="hidden" value="{{ $colorrr }}" id="my_color" /> next i copy var color = $("#my_color").val(); to my script then i write eventColor: color, and all event is red

Comment: okay, for this you need to pass color for each records. but now you got your original question's answer. You can pass variable to your JS.

Comment: thx i trying do this 2 days;p and its reallly anoying just today i figure how check if event exist in table but i cant pass color each records becouse i must checking if event exist so i dont know how i fix it